# Every time I open my shop activity it crashes

Tags: java, android-studio-2.0

Here is my code in my shop activity class, every time I run it, it crashed and I don't know why. I'm just a beginner in Android studio so I'm just experimenting to make an app.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import andrstrong textoid.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;

import static com.example.dazx15.spaceevasion.R.*;

 public class ShopActivity extends Activity {
 final Button buy1 = (Button) findViewById(id.buy_1);

private int best = 0;
private int coin=0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    buy1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(layout.activity_shop);



}
 //when you click the buy button
public void buySpaceship()
{
    coin=GamePanel.coin;
    if(coin<=500)
    {
        coin=coin - 500;
        buy1.setText("OWNED");
        buy1.setClickable(false);

    }
 }
 public void update() {
    best = GamePanel.best;
    GamePanel.coin=coin;

    //if the score is 500 above
    if (best <= 500) {
        buy1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and please don't you phrases like please help me.

Comment: I forgot also worth to read  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
final Button buy1 = (Button) findViewById(id.buy_1);
```

to

```
final Button buy1;
```

And your `onCreate` should look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(layout.activity_shop);
    buy1 = (Button)findViewById(id.buy_1);
    buy1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Your app crashed because of this line:

```
final Button buy1 = (Button) findViewById(id.buy_1);
```

You wanted to initialize the button right? However, that statement is executed when a new instance of the activity is created (I mean when the constructor is called, not `onCreate`). At that time, views in the activity have not been laid out yet! This leads to `findViewById` not finding a view, so it returns `null`.

Now in `onCreate`, you tried to set the visibility of `buy_1` to invisible. However, since `buy_1` is null, there is nothing to set! Hence, a null pointer exception is thrown and your app crashed.

Comment: thanks mr sweeper :) but I have another question how can I update the button buy1 because it's not updating when I run my app still not visible

Comment: @dazx15 of course it's not visible! You set the button's visibility to `INVISIBLE` in `onCreate`!

Comment: I set invisble because I want to set it visible if the score reach 500 so if my score(best) is equal or greater 500 the button buy1 update to visble thats what I want to do

Comment: @dazx15 Then just call `update()` in `onCreate`. Also, the condition in `update` is incorrect. You should use `>=` instead of `<=`